# Minecraft Inventory Problems

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was on Minecraft the other day and I encountered a problem.  Normally on my Minecraft I click an item once and I an move it around my inventory at will.  Although when I tried it the other day, I had to click the item and drag it to move it anywhere.  It started when I loaded up the Vechs Super Hostile, Inferno Mines off of Minecraft forums. I've tried deleting Minecraft and re-downloading it, restarting Minecraft, and shutting down the computer.  Any and all help would be appreciated on the matter ASAP.  I really like this game and I don't want to have to deal with this annoying feature on adventure maps.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen often? If so, then other people may be experiencing this problem. I do not experience it so it may be something related to your key board. If it doesn't happen often, I suggest you ignore it because it only takes away like 1 second every time (Excluding the use of chests).